# FindRoot of a function

Tags: roots, mathematica

I am trying to find root of this function using Mathematica but I think the value I get is incorrect, can anyone advise me on this[image: The function][image: My Mathematica coding]

Comment: Does $\lambda$ depend on $n$? If not, then your answer will be the same each time, just with different subscripts.

Comment: You don't understand how to use Mathematica in this case. Your expression `f[x_]:=FindRoot[...]` should be `f[n_]:=FindRoot[...]` instead. Then you can use `Do[Print[f[n]],{n,30}]`. Your other mistake is to use a subscripted variable. Instead use `xn` or some other ordinary variable. In any case, this is **not** a mathematics question.